# Sbt 0.12.4+ required on project import

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm currently reading the `Play for Scala: Covers Play 2` book by Peter Hilton (publisher: Manning) , and trying to stick to the versions they've outlined in the book (Play version 2.1.1).

I downloaded the new IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE app and installed it. I'm currently importing the project, and it's failing because it wants a version of sbt that is 0.12.4 or greater.

[image: Build failing]

This issue occurred in 13 the other day, but I haven't had time to resolve it, so please, no recommendations to go back to 13 :)

Here is the meat of the issue:
When I type `sbt --version` on the CLI, it prints `sbt launcher version 0.13.6.` I have a "greater" version, but it appears that IDEA doesn't recognize this.

In an effort to specify my own SBT launcher JAR, I pointed my custom launcher (in IDEAs global settings) to the one in `/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.6/libexec/sbt-launch.jar`, but the build also failed with the same error.

As you may have guessed at this point, I have used Homebrew to install and manage Scala and sbt. When I first started working with Scala back in February, I remember having to make a few small tweaks in my settings to get IDEA to find Scala, but my version of IDEA 14 is totally fresh -- I did not import any previous settings. I downloaded the Scala and sbt plugins and they appear to be properly configured after a cursory look and creation of a new test project.

Here is what I'm failing to understand:
First, and most obvious, why would an sbt version that meets the supposed requirement (0.12.4+) fail with version 0.13.*?

Second, is the bundled sbt with IDEA also greater than this version? Is there possibly an sbt flag somewhere in my system that's pointing it to an earlier version? A side note, I have a few versions of sbt in my "Cellar", but all are greater than 0.13.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had a look at the code samples from Manning's website, and the `project/build.properties` files for each project specify `sbt.version=0.12.2`. My guess is that the Intellij Scala plugin only supports SBT 0.12.4, and cannot import you project which is configured to use an older version (hence why it recommends that you "update your project definition").

You should try using `sbt.version=0.12.4` in the `project/build.properties` file.

Generally speaking, keep in mind that when an SBT version is specified in `project/build.properties`, the SBT launcher downloads the specified version and uses it to build the project. In your case, that means that the SBT 0.13.6 launcher will download SBT 0.12.2 and use that version to build the project.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue for me, and clarified a lot for me. I wish I could upvote this more than just once.

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, if you are interested in getting a better understanding of SBT, I can recommend the book "SBT in Action" (currently available as an early access preview from Manning Publishing, it's not finished yet) - but the documentation on [the SBT website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/documentation.html) is a good place to start as well.

Comment: Thank you, I think most of my frustration with Scala comes from a lack of understanding sbt, so that would probably make my life easier. Cheers, and many thanks for your help and recommendations!

Comment: @EricKeyte I did it for you :)

Comment: I tried it editing that file in 14.1.4 Ultimate, closed and reopened the project, and saw repeated "SBT: [error] Type error in expression" in the status line at the bottom. I killed it eventually. Anyone had luck with 14?